# networkx add_node with specific position

Tags: python, networkx

I am still a beginner with networkx
I want to add multiple types of nodes in different position, I used the following code

```
pos = {0: (40, 20), 1: (20, 30), 2: (40, 30), 3: (30, 10)} 
X=nx.Graph()
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(X,pos,node_size=3000,nodelist=[0,1,2,3],node_color='r')
```

but when I want to access the Graph X , if I type X.node it returns an empty list
and if I want to add more nodes I have to set their positions in the beginning using pos dictionary.

How can I  add  nodes to a graph in a specific location x and y using add_node()

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want to accomplish, but I think you want to add nodes to the graph, draw them in the wanted positions and still be able to access them in the graph object.

Since you don't add the nodes to the graph, that would be a start:

```python
X.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
```

Then you don't have to specify the node list when drawing the graph, and thus you don't have to change the code in two different places when adding new nodes.

If you want the position of the node as a node attribute, you could do that as well:

```python
for n, p in pos.iteritems():
    X.nodes[n]['pos'] = p
```

Just note that these positions won't be used as the position when drawing the graph, it has to be set explicitly. You could then draw and display the graph with:

```python
nx.draw(X, pos)
plt.show()
```

assuming that you did the import `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`.

Comment: And to be clear, the positions specified in pos are the same (x,y) coordinates passed to axes.scatter, so it's like over to the right x, and up y.

Comment: Really helpful answer, thank you very much! Is there a function from networkx to calculate the euklidic distance between two nodes?

Comment: @fuuman I might be late with this one, but as far as I know there is no direct function to compute the Euclidean distance between two nodes. As a reference, you could use this answer which was given to me a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330642/python-edge-length-distribution-of-a-regular-network?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: `pos` should be a dict? I would like to use a 2d-array as positions. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm using Networkx 2.5, yes, it is possible. It's equivalent to a dictionary `{i:v for i,v in enumerate(pos)}` and `IndexError` is raised in case there is an index in `range(len(pos))` that is not present in `X.nodes()`. Hence this is usable only if `X.nodes()` are numbers in `range(len(pos))`

Answer (score 78):

You can use the following approach to set individual node positions and then extract the "pos" dictionary to use when drawing.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G=nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_node(1,pos=(1,1))

In [4]: G.add_node(2,pos=(2,2))

In [5]: G.add_edge(1,2)

In [6]: pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')

In [7]: pos
Out[7]: {1: (1, 1), 2: (2, 2)}

In [8]: nx.draw(G,pos)
```

**UPDATE**

Add drawing

[image]