# Drawing specific graph with Networkx and plotly

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

I'm new at networkx and I want to draw a defined graph with Networkx and plotly. The graph is defined as follows:

```
pos = {0: (20, 10), 1: (20, 20), 2: (30, 10), 3: (30, 20), 4: (50, 15)} 
X=nx.Graph()
Gr.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
Gr.add_edge(0,3)
Gr.add_edge(0,2)
Gr.add_edge(1,2)
Gr.add_edge(3,4)
```

In order to make nodes clickable, as showed in the plotly tutorial (https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/), I used the code written there. The problem is that when I run the code below:

```
for node in Gr.nodes():
    x, y = Gr.nodes[node]['pos']
    node_x.append(x)
    node_y.append(y)
```

it shows me an the error:

```
<ipython-input-38-a80b1db2d250> in <module>
      2 node_y = []
      3 for node in Gr.nodes():
----> 4     x, y = Gr.nodes[node]['pos']
      5     node_x.append(x)
      6     node_y.append(y)

KeyError: 'pos'
```

The same thing happens with edges. I don't know what to do, knowing that this code works fine with random networks shown in the example of the url above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804730/networkx-add-node-with-specific-position

Comment: Does this answer your question? [networkx add\_node with specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804730/networkx-add-node-with-specific-position)

Comment: @TomRon. Yes the second answer does. Thank's a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the answer from this url: [networkx add_node with specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804730/networkx-add-node-with-specific-position). Thanks to @TomRon. The idea is to define each node separately and add the instruction below to get position and use it with plotly

```
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')
```