# Is it possible to draw a networkx graph in plotly without a position coordinate for each node?

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

I have a large `networkx` MultiDiGraph `G` (see sample of it in the figure):
[image]

I can do all the usual `networkx` things like

```
print(len(G.nodes())) # sample has 72
```

The way I'm constructing the graph is iterating over nodes and edges triples and adding edges:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
for subj, obj, rel in triples_list:
    G.add_edge(subj, obj, label=rel) # subj = node 1, obj = node 2, rel = relation/edge name
```

I was trying to follow the `plotly` [tutorial](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/) on plotting this, which seem to require a position for each node. I found these SO questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64819247/drawing-specific-graph-with-networkx-and-plotly), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804730/networkx-add-node-with-specific-position)) which show how to add the position for each node, either given a list of positions, or manually.

The issue is that I don't have a list of positions, nor do I care where the nodes will be in the graph (optimally as spread out as possible for easier visualization). Manual annotation of position for each node is sub-optimal as I have many of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use some layout algorithm from the networkX package to generate a position:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
```

This creates a position the for nodes [using the Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html). Usually this works well, depending on what you want to visualize, you may want to explore [other layout algorithms](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout)...

If you want the position to stay the same for the same network provide a seed.

Comment: Thanks! And then what? Do you recreate the graph using this position information? Or is there a simpler way to visualize it

Comment: Yes, you will need to pass the `pos` as a keyword argument (fox nx commands it's usually `pos=pos`).

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Thanks, that worked! Though I can't seem to create the same graph as I did with `networkx`. In particular, I haven't found a way to plot directed edges similarly

Comment: If you share your code we could maybe help you. I dont understand the problem you have.