# Change networkx graph transparency of each edge and node

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

When drawing graphs in Networkx, I am wondering if there is a way to specify `alpha` for each edge and node - similar to how the `node_color` or `edge_color` can be a list of colors. The goal is to be able to selectively highlight a subgraph of a larger graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [`draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html), you can pass in an array of floats to the `alpha` argument like you would do for `node_color`.

**Edit based on comment from @AveragePythonEnjoyer**

[`draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html) **does** offer the same functionality, so you can pass a list of floats to the `alpha` argument the same length as the number of edges for that one as well!

If the lists that you pass into the `alpha` argument are shorter than the number of nodes/edges, the values will cycle through the list then restart at the beginning until the number of nodes/edges is covered.  If the list is longer than the number of nodes/edges, only the number of values corresponding to the number of nodes/edges will be used.

Both `draw_networkx_nodes` and `draw_networkx_edges` require you to pass in a `pos` argument for node positions, so those must be defined in advance.

Comment: It does offer the same functionality.

Comment: Good to know, thank you! Updated answer with that information. Should have tested it myself before posting instead of just trusting the documentation!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. For reference, if anyone else also needed to extract `pos` in order to get this working, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11809184/14651805) helped me as well.