# Can the transparency of the link be specified in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx, alpha

#### Abstract

I am trying to find a way to make the nodes transparent. In the simple case, the transparency of a node is simply specified by the "alpha" option of "nx.draw".
However, I thought I could specify the transparency with a list, just as I specified the color with a list, but failed. Do you know the reason for this?

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node('A')
G.add_node('B')
G.add_node('C')
G.add_node('D')
G.add_node('E')

G.add_edge('A', 'B')
G.add_edge('A', 'C')
G.add_edge('A', 'D')
G.add_edge('B', 'D')
G.add_edge('D', 'E')

node_alpha = [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2]

nx.draw(G, alpha=node_alpha, with_labels = True)

plt.figure()
```

The following error occurred

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/Python36/transparency.py", line 19, in <module>
    nx.draw(G, alpha=node_alpha, with_labels = True)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 123, in draw
    draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=ax, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 336, in draw_networkx
    draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, arrows=arrows, **edge_kwds)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 684, in draw_networkx_edges
    alpha=alpha,
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1391, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 213, in __init__
    self.update(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 998, in update
    ret.append(func(v))
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 834, in set_alpha
    super().set_alpha(alpha)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 930, in set_alpha
    raise TypeError('alpha must be a float or None')
TypeError: alpha must be a float or None
```

We believe that the image will be as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit*: as answered by @Andrew (with a further reference to @AveragePythonEnjoyer) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106862/20148180), it is possible to add a list of `alpha` values. This is not consistent with the documentation as of `networkx` version `2.8`, however it should be fixed in future releases (see [this PR](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/6254)).

Passing an array or a list of `alpha` values is supported by both [`nx.draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes) and [`nx.draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html). However, right now the doc string for `draw_networkx_edges` is not consistent with the allowed `alpha` types, so one can refer to the documentation for [`nx.draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes):

> alpha : float or array of floats (default=None)
> The node transparency.  This can be a single alpha value,
> in which case it will be applied to all the nodes of color. Otherwise,
> if it is an array, the elements of alpha will be applied to the colors
> in order (cycling through alpha multiple times if necessary).

Comment: `nx.draw_networkx_edges` actually does support an array of floats!  It's not listed in the documentation, but it was pointed out to me in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106862/20148180).  You can't use an array in `nx.draw` since `NetworkX` won't know whether you're referring to the nodes or the edges (and since the number of nodes can be different than the number of edges), but if you draw the nodes and edges separately, you can pass arrays to the alpha value for each.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for pointing this out, seems docs need updating.

Comment: I updated the answer and submitted a PR to fix the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As advised, I was able to solve the problem using `nx.draw_networkx_edges`. Thanks.

```
import networkx as nx
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_graph(edges):
   G = nx.DiGraph()
   G.add_edges_from(edges)
   pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
   alphas = [1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2]

   nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_color = "b",node_size = 300,alpha = alphas)
   nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,arrows = False)
   nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,font_size = 12)
   plt.axis('off')
   plt.show()
   
edges = [("A","B"),("A","C"),("A","D"),("B","D"),("D","E")]
draw_graph(edges)
```

[image]

Comment: Great reproducible example!