# Python - Network X - set node transparency

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, pyvis

I've got a network of Nodes graph where I set the color when adding a node.

```py
add_node(..., color='red')
add_node(..., color='blue')
add_node(..., color='green')
```

Later on I take a subset and update their color

```py
subset = [n for n,d in Graph.nodes(...]
for node in subset:
  nx.set_node_attributes(Graph {str(node):'#000000'}, color)
```

This works and the color updates, but I'm struggling when I decide to change from updating the color to changing the transparency of this subset of nodes, alpha doesn't work.

```py
subset = [n for n,d in Graph.nodes(...]
for node in subset:
  nx.set_node_attributes(Graph {str(node):.5}, alpha)
```

How do I set the transparency of the original color?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a full reproducible code? (setting a minimal graph, and the exact used code for plotting) together with the image output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change networkx graph transparency of each edge and node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106232/change-networkx-graph-transparency-of-each-edge-and-node)

Answer (score 0):

When `add_node` you can add `alpha` attributes and update it later. Here is the sample code

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
 
G = nx.Graph()
 
G.add_node(1, color='red', alpha=1)
G.add_node(2, color='blue', alpha=1)
G.add_node(3, color='green', alpha=1)

# Define your subset of nodes
subset = [1, 2]  # For example, nodes 1 and 2

# Update the alpha values for the nodes in the subset
for node in subset:
    G.nodes[node]['alpha'] = 0.1  # Set alpha to 0.1 for these nodes
 
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
 
node_colors = [mcolors.to_rgba(G.nodes[node]['color'], alpha=G.nodes[node]['alpha']) for node in G]
 
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color=node_colors, node_size=500)

plt.show()
```

Here is the result with node 1 and 2 are transparent , but node 3 is not.
[image]

You can check on [my kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/heinzmdsiahaan/notebook83cc59306d)